# Passing optional configuration variables on class initialization in PHP

Tags: php, class, oop

Bear with me please as I'm quite new to the OOP concept so I might just be way wrong in my thinking here.

I'm developing a class for some functionality I use quite often and I would like it to be configurable in any new project on initialization. The caveat here is that I'd like to set certain default variables and allow them to stay un-configured if the defaults are alright. Here is a bit of code to try to make the concept a bit clearer.

```
class someClass{

    // Setting parameter defaults
    private $param_a = 60;
    private $param_b = 100;

   /*
    * The construct function. What I'd like to do here is make the param_a and param_b optional,
    * i.e if it doesn't get set on initialization it takes the defaults from the class.
   */

   function __construct($param_a, $param_b, $foo){
       // do something ...
   }    
}

$foo = "some value";

// init example using defaults
$someclass = new someClass($foo); // $param_a and $param_b should be 60 and 100 respectively

// init example using custom options
$someclass = new someClass(40, 110, $foo);
```

Am I going in the right direction as far as how to set up class configuration? If so, how do I make param_a and param_b optional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function __construct($foo, $param_a = 60, $param_b = 100){
   // do something ...
}
```

You could supply required method arguments first, and then ones with default parameters afterwards, making them optional.

Then assign these to the class variables inside the constructor.

Another way would be to use func_get_args() and parse this.

Comment: Thanks alot. As an idiot I didn't look in the PHP manual before asking and it's right there, third in the Function Arguments section. Will check this answer as correct in a few minutes (I believe I need to wait 6 more). Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You could just make the constructor take a general $args argument and merge it with an array of defaults:

```
public function __construct($args = array()) {

    $args = array_merge(array(
        'param_a'   => 60,
        'param_b'   => 100,
        'foo'       => null
    ), $args);

    foreach($args as $key => $val) {
        $this->$key = $val;
    }

}
```

Comment: Excellent solution as well, although foo would never be optional or null so I'm not sure this would work.

Comment: If that's the case I would go with Jack's solution. I would use my solution for a larger number of arguments or if you may need to add or remove arguments often. You can also check if a required parameter is not specified and throw an exception.